# cname and wordpress domain map

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, wordpress, cname-record

I have a domain like this (www.example.com.br) and I'm also the manager for the domain and the nameservers too (the nameservers are Bind).

Now I have a blog from wordpress.com and I wanted to map domain to www.88.example.com.br. The wordpress suggested to use this:

```
88.example.com.br IN CNAME example88.wordpress.com.
```

Can I create a zone file with only that CNAME ? Can I use other zone file that already exists, like this ?

```
$ORIGIN 88.example.com.br.

88.example.com.br  IN CNAME exmple88.wordpress.com.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-existing-domain/

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a zone for `example.com.br` you can put the suggested record in there, like so:

```
88.example.com.br. IN CNAME example88.wordpress.com.
```

If you do not have an `example.com.br` zone you will need to create one. (And it will need at least `SOA` + `NS` records at the zone apex in addition to this new record.)